# Transfer variable between asp pages by web request

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

can any one explain how to transfer a variable between asp pages by web request. Web request means post method and also suggest a best method in asp for transfering variable between the asp.net pages

Comment: Are you referring to Classic ASP or ASP.NET? Your tags are for .NET, but your question appears to be about Classic ASP.

Comment: thanks.i am refering asp.net only

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways that you can pass variables between ASP.NET pages-

1. In Session State
2. In Query String
3. Reading Values from the source page 
   (exposed as properties)

[MSDN article - How to Pass Values between ASP.NET pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

I have never had the need to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to pass values between pages. As I understand it, this was a standard method of passing values in Classic ASP. Whilst you can still use this method in ASP.NET (as demonstrated by [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551234/transfer-variable-between-asp-pages-by-web-request/551244#551244)), I think you will find one of the method's above more concise and one to fit different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString() or System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues()

Answer (score 1):

You have some alternatives, you can use the [query string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx), the [session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx), using [Server.Transfer and the HttpContext](http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/WebLog/familjones/archive/2004/04/08/11020.aspx).

You can do [Cross-Page Postbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) and the last page is exposed by the [PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) property...

Comment: The only downside that I have found with Cross Page Postbacks is to do with Server Side validation - the validation check is carried out on the page that is cross posted back to! I haven't seen a way around this

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by web request?

You can post it to another page using web request.

```
string myvar = "abc";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
using(Stream writeStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] bytes = encoding.GetBytes("myvar=" + myvar);
    writeStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

And retrieve it there using

```
string myvar = Request.Post["myvar"];
```

But may be you should consider other options?

You can transfer it using Session or Application objects.

You can transfer it by query string.

Comment: what i mean by web request is post method only. Also suggest which method is best for asp.